# NoMethodError when requesting datetime element

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, datetime

I try to request a datetime entry in my database with ruby on rails. This works just fine in a linux environment but in my windows environment I get a NoMethodError. When debugging it I found out that the errors occurs at line 201 of the schema_definitions.rb when casting the datetime string to a time

```
def fast_string_to_time(string)
            if string =~ Format::ISO_DATETIME
              microsec = ($7.to_f * 1_000_000).to_i <<====== This is line 201
              new_time $1.to_i, $2.to_i, $3.to_i, $4.to_i, $5.to_i, $6.to_i, microsec
            end
          end
```

When watching the $7 I get nil, seems that $7 is not initialized. What is $7 in this context? My string is

```
2011-04-01 10:48:57
```

This is the part of the trace after validate is called on an entry of an array that should contain the date

```
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:201:in `fast_string_to_time'
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:139:in `string_to_time'
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb:78:in `type_cast'
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:83:in `read_attribute'
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/base.rb:1558:in `attributes'
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/base.rb:1558:in `each'
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/base.rb:1558:in `attributes'
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:57:in `attribute_method?'
activemodel (3.0.1) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:394:in `match_attribute_method?'
activemodel (3.0.1) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:393:in `each'
activemodel (3.0.1) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:393:in `match_attribute_method?'
activemodel (3.0.1) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:378:in `respond_to?'
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:52:in `respond_to?'
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:268:in `deprecated_callback_method'
activerecord (3.0.1) lib/active_record/validations.rb:57:in `valid?'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format::ISO_DATETIME is a Regexp:
/\A(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d) (\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)(.\d+)?\z/

The 7th capture is the fractional seconds (e.g. ".123"), which is converted to a float and then converted to microseconds. In your string, $7 would be nil, but that's not a problem, because nil.to_f is just 0.0.
Try executing nil.to_f in a console to make sure you get 0.0.

Are you sure the NoMethodError is caused by that line? Can you post the backtrace?

Comment: The NoMethodError seems to occur in the whiny_nil.rb. Maybe there could be the problem as it is working in production mode? Anyhow this would not be nice as there is an error in testing.

Comment: in netbeans I tried to do nil.to_f as a watch variable and it returned nil, when doing nil.to_i 0 is returned

Comment: when commenting out the line microsec = ($7.to_f * 1_000_000).to_i in fast_string_to_time and setting microsec to 0, it works

Comment: Try running: ruby -e "p nil.to_f"   (If you set the RUBYOPT environment variable to require any libraries, you should unset it while running the command). Does that still return nil ?  Also, are your ruby versions the same between linux and windows?

Comment: Another thing to try. Run this command to trace the to_f function call; the to_f output lines should start with "c-call" and "c-return". If they don't, some library is intercepting the call. Command to run:  ruby -e "set_trace_func proc {|event, file, line, id, binding, classname| printf %Q{%8s %s:%-2d %10s %8s\n}, event, file, line, id, classname }; nil.to_f; set_trace_func nil"

Comment: line -e:1                false
  c-call -e:1        to_f NilClass
c-return -e:1        to_f NilClass
    line -e:1                false
  c-call -e:1  set_trace_func   Kernel

Comment: @xelluloid That output looks the same as mine, so it looks like nothing is intercepting the built-in call. Please also post the output of `ruby -e "p nil.to_f"` as I mentioned 3 comments up. This will show whether your built-in to_f returns 0.0. (I've found that NetBeans debugger doesn't always show data consistently.)